# convert numeric to string with no decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a rather large stored procedure that I'm working with, so I'll only include the snippet that I'm concerned with:

```
                QUOTENAME(isnull(NumberCount,'0'), '"'),
                QUOTENAME( isnull(QualifiedCount,'0'), '"'),
                QUOTENAME((isnull(RevenueAmount,'0')), '"'),
                QUOTENAME(isnull(CurrencyAmount,'0'), '"')
```

In the output, all of the records that have a NULL value display with the expected value of '0', except for the RevenueAmount column. That displays as '0.0'. This is because it was declared as NUMERIC(20,2). How do I get it to display a value of '0'? I thought setting an explicit value of '0' in the isnull condition would take care of it, but it doesn't.

Advice?

Comment: I guess your RevenueAmount comes in as 0 not NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display `"0"` instead of `"0.0"` when RevenueAmount is `0` or `null`:

```
case IsNull(RevenueAmount, 0)
    when 0 then QUOTENAME('0', '"')
    else QUOTENAME(RevenueAmount, '"')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this for the `RevenueAmount` column. The trick is to test for null or 0 and convert to the right string format

```
case RevenueAmount
    when null then QUOTENAME('0.0', '"')
    when 0 then QUOTENAME('0.0', '"')
else cast(QUOTENAME(isnull(RevenueAmount,'0'), '"') as varchar(20)) 
end
as [RevenueAmount]
```